# iOS 8 Keyboard Delegate Methods not getting Called

Tags: keyboard, ios8, keyboard-events, uikeyboard

In iOS 8, When I Press Down key  (Right Bottom Corner) of Keyboard,
Keyboard gets Disappear, but its delegate methods:

```
1.- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField; & 
2.- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField;
```

Not getting Called for respective TextField.
But When I Click on another TextField immediately those getting called for Previous Textfield.

It was working fine in iOS 7.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to be a bug. Positive side is that it is only on simulator and it is working correctly on a real device.